# Did the unmanned orbital test of the Buran shuttle yield any science results?

Tags: soviet-union, buran

This question was inspired by the question [Did Sputnik 1 tell us more than “beep”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46333/29286)

[The Soviet Buran programme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buran_programme) only had one orbital flight, mission 1K1, on 15 November 1988.

**Did that mission yield any results beyond the fact that Buran was operational?**

Comment: Would *engineering results* be included?

Comment: @uhoh I'm not sure, I guess if it's results that were discovered through the flight, rather than confirmed that qualifies

Comment: Other results can be put in an answer too, but will not be an accepted answer

Comment: This question could be asked for every maiden flight of orbital spacecraft. Just saying. Looking forward to seeing this being answered.

Comment: @EverydayAstronaut Yes. I am asking the question because Buran only had its maiden flight, so it never produced any of the science data it was initially meant to provide (or ferry to/from a space station)

Comment: On sites russianspaceweb.com and buran.ru I don't see any info about scientific investigations during the flight. So probably there were none.