# Calculating Orbital Velocity without Semi-Major-Axis

Tags: orbital-mechanics, celestial-mechanics

When playing Kerbal Space Program, I realized that there is a difference between surface speed and orbital speed; this difference is quite variable, although the Kerbin's surface speed is only 175 m/s.

My question is: how do NASA or SpaceX calculate the orbital velocity? One of the many ways to do this is using the [vis-viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation), but the vis-viva equation needs the value of the semi-major-axis, so my question now is: how can you figure out the orbital velocity without knowing the semi-major axis?

Comment: It's a good question! I'd guess that they start with a gravity model of the body and a bunch of position measurements via some combination of self-reported positions (by telemetry) using GPS or other location-providing satellites like TDRS and by ground observations of positions and velocities, then adjusting/fitting simulated trajectories in order to best fit all of those observations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But supposing if they didn't have satellites or all that technology, if we were talking about the launch of sputnik 1 for example. would there be any formula to calculate the orbital speed or the Semi Major Axis without depending on each other?

Comment: It's just a comment, I think someone will write a full answer. But in your question you write "My question is how NASA or SpaceX calculate the orbital velocity?" Sputnik had a radio transmitter that "beeped" and could be tracked by radio, and I'm sure *several governments* independently did exactly the same kind of thing that is done today. The difference is that back then we didn't have a good gravity model of the Earth, so the fitting procedures on the first few satellites ever launched *gave us better gravity models!*

Comment: For more on that see [Did Sputnik 1 tell us more than “beep”? What science was improved by information gained from its orbiting the Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46333/12102) and other things linked there. Also see [1959 Peanuts cartoon about the Fischer ellipsoid (Earth is “pear-shaped”)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/234294/51174) and other things linked there.

Comment: Thanks! And sorry for any confusion